# Formatting cell to double

Tags: matlab, number-formatting, cell-array

I have text file in which the data is like (1,2),(3,4),1 (4,5),(6,7),1
I am reading the file in the matlab as:

```
A= textread('abc.txt', '%s');
```

the output is

```
A: 2x1 cell
(1,2),(3,4),1 
(4,5),(6,7),1
```

Anyone please help to convert this cell to double with the output

```
New_A= 5x2 double
1 2 3 4 1 
4 5 6 7 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your particular example, once you read the file, you can use [textscan](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

```
    A = {'(1,2),(3,4),1' 
         '(4,5),(6,7),1'};

    New_A = cell2mat(cellfun(@(line) cell2mat(textscan(line,'(%f,%f),(%f,%f),%f')), A, 'UniformOutput', 0));


New_A =

     1     2     3     4     1
     4     5     6     7     1
```

You can also do similar, line by line, as they are read from the file.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Nope. I executed this on Matlab. So it works in Matlab.

Comment: I am using the same code for the text file have data like 
`000001 -1000002 -1` the output using `textread` is 4x1 cell
then how can use the `cell2mat` function to 2x2 matrix in double.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [**`regexprep`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html), [**`cell2mat`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) and [**`str2num`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) as follows:

```
A = {'(1,2),(3,4),1'
     '(4,5),(6,7),1'};  % This is what you get after this: A= textread('abc.txt', '%s'); 
New_A = regexprep(A,'(\(|\))',''); %Removing the brackets ()
New_A = str2num(cell2mat(New_A))   %Converting char cell to numeric matrix
```

Comment: I am using the same code for the text file have data like `000001 -1000002 -1` the output using `textread` is 4x1 cell then how can use the `cell2mat` function to 2x2 matrix in double.

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion I will post new Question and I know its not code writing service.